# Getting error "missing comma" when running an SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I fix this query? I get a "missing comma" error.

```
INSERT INTO Vehicle 
    VALUES (
        '0001', 
        '01234567890123451', 
        Toy, 
        Prius, 
        TO_DATE('2020', 'YYYY'), 
        26,000, 
        5,800, 
        to_date('03-15-2020','mm-dd-yyy'), 
        10a
    );
```

Comment: What is `10a`? It should probably be enclosed in single quotes.

Comment: Also, ALWAYS include the list of columns in INSERT statements.

Comment: Is `26,000` supposed to be a numeric value? Looks like 26 and 000 to the SQL parser.

Comment: It is interesting that you get that error. While there are many mistakes in your code, as others have pointed out, I still can't see which of those would throw "missing comma". Is that the **exact** code you are running, or did you change it somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You need single quotes around strings.  In addition, I would recommend a date literal:

```
Insert into Vehicle
    values ('0001', '01234567890123451', 'Toy', 'Prius', date '2020-01-01', 26, 000, 5, 800, date '2020-03-15', '10a');
```

I am assuming that `26,000` and `5,800` are each actually two columns.  If they are one remove the comma.

The expression `TO_DATE('2020', 'YYYY')` seems like an awkward way to get the first day of an arbitrary month in 2020.  Just use explicit `date` values.

I also strongly, strongly recommend that you list the columns explicitly for the insert.  That is one way to prevent unexpected and hard-to-debug errors.

Comment: `to_date('2020', 'yyyy')` does ***not*** return 1 January 2020. It returns the first day of the CURRENT calendar month, but for year 2020. (The default day is 1; the default month is the current month). Very likely the OP is unaware of this, and therefore he does NOT want that behavior, but your answer may confuse him and other readers.

Answer (score 0):

Through a process of elimination (and guessing at the layout of your table) I was able to determine that the "missing comma" error is being caused by the lack of single-quote/apostrophe characters around `10a`. I created a `VEHICLE` table which attempts to mimic your table (although the field names may differ), and when I put single-quotes around `10a` the error changes from `ORA-00917: missing comma` to `ORA-00913: too many values`. A fully-corrected version of the query might be:

```
INSERT INTO Vehicle 
    VALUES (
        '0001', 
        '01234567890123451', 
        'Toy', 
        'Prius', 
        TO_DATE('2020', 'YYYY'), 
        26000, 
        5800, 
        to_date('03-15-2020','mm-dd-yyyy'), 
        '10a'
    );
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=27ca74990534fdd3631a13a6aee908eb)